# How to show my if statement result in the table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I already create if statement for grade student but I'm trying to show my result into my table but it's doesn't want to appear in my table. This is my code. I already have var that stored in the table. I will put evidence in my question.
Should I put in the for loop? so I can show the result to my table

Sorry, I'm so new with JavaScript

This my table
[image: My Table]

```
var score = [
    ['Mary', 65],
    ['Jim', 70],
    ['Albert', 85],
    ['Carroll', 90],
    ['Francis', 50],
    ['Micheal', 62],
    ['John', 76],
    ['Tim', 88],
    ['Carlos', 64],
    ['Steven', 45]
  ],
  table = document.getElementById("table");

for (var i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
  // create a new row
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
  for (var j = 0; j < score[i].length; j++) {
    // create a new cell
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);

    // add value to the cell
    cell.innerHTML = score[i][j];
  }
}

if (score >= 80) {
  grade = 'High Distinction';
}
if (score >= 70 && score < 80) {
  grade = 'Distinction';
} else if (score >= 60 && score < 70) {
  grade = 'Credit';
} else if (score >= 50 && marks < 60) {
  grade = 'Pass';
} else(score < 50) {
  grade = 'Fail';
}
```

Comment: Where is `score` defined?

Comment: The score will be print in my table

Comment: I don't see the variable `score` defined anywhere.

Comment: So, I need to define the variable score into my javascript?

Comment: It's the very first line of the code. @PrerakSola

Comment: But `score` is an array, what do you mean by `if (score > 80)`?

Comment: @Barmar my bad. I just went straight to the `for` loop.

Comment: The score is the grade of students. So if the student gets a score more than 80. The result will grade as High Distinction grade

Comment: @DRGN `score` is an `array`. You can not compare an array to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement should be inside the loop, and test `score[i][1]`.

Another problem is that you don't put a condition after `else`, only after `if` and `else if`.

It's not necessary to test the upper bounds in your `else if` statements, since the previous `if` ensures that the score is below that.

```js
var score = [
    ['Mary', 65],
    ['Jim', 70],
    ['Albert', 85],
    ['Carroll', 90],
    ['Francis', 50],
    ['Micheal', 62],
    ['John', 76],
    ['Tim', 88],
    ['Carlos', 64],
    ['Steven', 45]
  ],
  table = document.getElementById("table");

for (var i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
  // create a new row
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
  for (var j = 0; j < score[i].length; j++) {
    // create a new cell
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);
    // add value to the cell
    cell.innerHTML = score[i][j];
  }
  var grade;
  var this_score = score[i][1];
  if (this_score >= 80) {
    grade = 'High Distinction';
  } else if (this_score >= 70) {
    grade = 'Distinction';
  } else if (this_score >= 60) {
    grade = 'Credit';
  } else if (this_score >= 50) {
    grade = 'Pass';
  } else {
    grade = 'Fail';
  }
  cell = newRow.insertCell(j);
  cell.innerHTML = grade;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Score</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding me @Barmar

Comment: quick question why var this_score = score [i][1]?

Comment: So I don't have to keep writing `score[i][1]` in every `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code in the snippet below:

1. Replaced the **for(i++)** with **forEach()** (both of them)
2. Created a function that returns the score (the string)
3. Used the new function to add the score string to each element, and THEN write out the table

```js
var score = [
    ['Mary', 65],
    ['Jim', 70],
    ['Albert', 85],
    ['Carroll', 90],
    ['Francis', 50],
    ['Micheal', 62],
    ['John', 76],
    ['Tim', 88],
    ['Carlos', 64],
    ['Steven', 45]
  ],
  table = document.getElementById("table");

function addScore(score) {
  let grade = ''
  if (score >= 80) {
    grade = 'High Distinction';
  } else if (score >= 70 && score < 80) {
    grade = 'Distinction';
  } else if (score >= 60 && score < 70) {
    grade = 'Credit';
  } else if (score >= 50 && marks < 60) {
    grade = 'Pass';
  } else {
    grade = 'Fail';
  }
  return grade
}

// iterating over the array
score.forEach((e, i) => {
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

  // adding score to each row
  e.push(addScore(e[1]))
  e.forEach((el, j) => {
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(j)
    cell.innerHTML = el
  })
})
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution